# Google coral developer board not working with HDMI LCD

Tags: display, hdmi, google-coral, weston

Just trying to connect the **Waveshare 10.1inch HDMI LCD display** for my Google coral developer board. As i am not sure about this...

**Weston service status:**

```
 weston.service - Weston Wayland Compositor (on tty7)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/weston.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-12-28 04:58:03 UTC; 48min ago
     Docs: man:weston(1)
           man:weston.ini(5)
           http://wayland.freedesktop.org/
  Process: 3873 ExecStart=/usr/bin/weston --log=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/weston.log (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3873 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 

Dec 28 04:58:02 zippy-orange systemd[1]: Starting Weston Wayland Compositor (on tty7)...
Dec 28 04:58:02 zippy-orange systemd[3873]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user mendel by mendel(ui
Dec 28 04:58:03 zippy-orange systemd[1]: weston.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 28 04:58:03 zippy-orange systemd[1]: weston.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 28 04:58:03 zippy-orange systemd[1]: Failed to start Weston Wayland Compositor (on tty7).
```

and also I have searched for solutions, (but not helped me out)

- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston/-/issues/204
- https://github.com/waveshare/LCD-show.git

Any suggestions or troubleshoot for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The ix8M kernel is limited in the range of clock speeds that it supports, and small HDMI monitors generally don't work with it.  You can see more about it here:

https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/HDMI-DRM-custom-resolution-and-clock-frequency/m-p/1029696